# Rust: Create New Vector Containing Elements Of Existing Vector With Minimal New Memory Allocation

Tags: rust

I am starting to learn Rust, and it's the first time I've ever worked in a language where you have to think about memory allocation (I've never used C).

As an exercise, I decided to see how I could create a new vector that includes some elements from another vector in addition to some new elements. My goal is to create a vector that maintains pointers to the data in the other vector rather than copying or cloning that data, so that new memory is only allocated for the additional elements. Is that what's happening in the code below, and/or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![vec![1], vec![2], vec![3]];
    let v0 = &v[0];
    let v1 = &v[1];
    let v2 = &vec![4];
    let v3 = vec![v0, v1, v2];
}
```

I used nested vectors because to me, this issue is more pertinent when you're working with data on the heap than on the stack, and vectors are allocated on the heap while integers are on the stack, but keep in mind that I'm a complete novice to this whole domain, so feel free to let me know if what I'm saying and doing makes no sense at all .

Comment: Yes, that's what's happening - `v3` is a vector of three vector references. The problem is that it's less useflu than you'd hope because, since you have shared references to all these vectors, you're no longer allowed to modify them.

Comment: Thanks, and your point about mutation is well taken. Coming from a functional background, this helps me to understand how memory allocation works by translating to an idiom I'm more familiar with, but I know that idiomatic Rust relies more on mutation. In any event, is there a better or more idiomatic way to accomplish the same thing my code accomplishes?

Comment: That's part of the problem: I'm not *really* sure what you're trying to accomplish. I mean, on a literal level it's clear, and I guess this is how you'd do it, but I don't understand how that's useful, or what you're trying to accomplish. Your question would be served by providing a use case or at least motivation for doing this.

Comment: I don't know if you're familiar with Clojure, but essentially I'm seeing how I could implement Clojure-style persistent immutable data in Rust in a memory-conservative way. Can I have an operation that does `v.conj(x)` where `v` is a persistent immutable vector, and the result is a new persistent immutable vector that does not mutate the original one, but also doesn't allocate any more new memory than necessary?

Comment: That can be done in Rust, see e.g. [this crate](https://docs.rs/im/15.0.0/im/), but it's far from simple and _definitely_ not a learning project. I would even go so far as to advise that you temporarily forget about clojure-style approach to memory management for now and try to learn the Rust way of doing things. If you just want to learn about the borrow checker and memory manipulation in Rust, I suggest [this nice book](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: From glancing at that book, it looks like it was written exactly for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to create a vector that maintains pointers to the data in the other vector rather than copying or cloning that data, so that new memory is only allocated for the additional elements. Is that what's happening in the code below[?]

Yes, `v3` contains references to the existing vectors that were in `v`. It doesn't create new ones or anything.

> this issue is more pertinent when you're working with data on the heap than on the stack, and vectors are allocated on the heap while integers are on the stack

This remark is not really true, although using non-Copy types does avoid fooling yourself when you're working on problems like this. Whether a value is on the stack, on the heap, or not on either is for Rust to decide; `vec![vec![1]]` vs. `vec![1]` would have the value inside the outermost vec just as much on the heap, if we were to guess what Rust would do.

Comment: Thanks! I have a related concern which is hopefully not too off-topic, but when you take a slice of a vector, the compiler wants all nested types to implement Clone, which suggests to me that slicing automatically clones. So is my approach also potentially a way to make a logical slice without cloning?

Comment: @grandinero *when you take a slice of a vector, the compiler wants all nested types to implement Clone* - Why do you think that? It's [not true](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17e3de5abde4146b59cd233f12e6b226).

Comment: You're right, I just realized I was calling `.to_vec` on the slice, and that was cloning the contents.